# Bash script run from cron

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron

I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
src="/home/user/testingscript"
for dir in $(ls "$src")
do
find ${src}/${dir}/ -type f -mtime +31 delete
done
```

It runs fine if i execute it from the terminal, but once i put it in the crontab like that:

```
* * * * * /bin/bash /home/user/script/mailboxclean.sh >> /home/user/mailboxcleanup.log 2>&1
```

or as:

```
* * * * * /home/user/script/mailboxclean.sh
```

it doesnt run.

I see no feedback in the syslog, apart that the script has been executed and in the mailboxcleanup.log where i am redirecting I see the followinh which doesnt really help:

```
/home/user/mailboxcleanup.log: 1: /home/user/mailboxcleanup.log: /bin/sh:: not found
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: It's strange you have `#!/bin/bash`, you call with `/bin/bash` and then you receive a `/bin/sh` error message.

Comment: not related to the question, but you should change the `for dir in $(ls "$src"); do find ${src}/${dir}/ -type f ....` to `for dir in "${src}"/*/ do ; find "${dir}" -type f .... `

Comment: @fedorqui: maybe bash is not in /bin ? ... ^^ then sh would complain it can't find it to execute the script? *OR* this is a /etc/crontab and "/bin/bash" is taken as the user, which can't be found and some bizarre consequence is that error message.

Comment: and shouldn't it be `-delete` instead of `delete` ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends where you put the script.

If you want it to be run via /etc/crontab: you need a 6th parameter before the command, specifying the user!

```
 * * * * * theuser /home/user/script/mailboxclean.sh
```

If you place it in someone's (root, or a user) crontab using `crontab -e`

```
 * * * * * /home/user/script/mailboxclean.sh
```

(ie, no 6th parameter, as the user is known)

Be careful that if you want to have it run daily/weekly/monthly by placing it under /etc/cron.*/, you need to REMOVE the extension (ie, call it `mailboxclean`) as otherwise it will simply be ignored

The most common cause of difference is that the script lack some environment variable when run via cron (or when placed underneath a /etc/cron.* directory)... Check for this (you could add a : `echo "=== set: ============ " ; set ; echo "=== env: ============ " ; env` at the beginning of your script while debugging, for example. Or just ensure you set **everything** you need correctly)

---

And not related to the question, but you should change the

```
for dir in $(ls "$src"); do find ${src}/${dir}/ -type f ....
```

to

```
for dir in "${src}"/*/ ; do find "${dir}" -type f ....
```

(see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls for infos on this, and many other (the rest of their site is great too, when you learn bash scripting))